# Pickle Package; EOFError: Ran out of input

Tags: python, pickle

I checked a bunch of threads similar to this but none of them worked, please help!!

```
    import pickle
    fileObject = open("/content/drive/MyDrive/mainlyric_corpus",'rb') 
    # pickle.dump(mainlyric_corpus,fileObject)   
    mainlyric_corpus = pickle.load(fileObject)
    fileObject.close()
```

```
EOFError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-80ae498fa657> in <module>()
      2 fileObject = open("/content/drive/MyDrive/mainlyric_corpus",'rb')
      3 # pickle.dump(mainlyric_corpus,fileObject)
----> 4 mainlyric_corpus = pickle.load(fileObject)
      5 fileObject.close()

EOFError: Ran out of input
```

Comment: Are you sure the file is complete? Errors like this are typically caused by `pickle` expecting some more data...

Comment: hmm, you are right. the files is apparently 0 b size, I wonder why it's 0b even though the file is created when I used the pickle.dump() function